# How to get global data from children in pidstat?

Tags: bash, operating-system

I want to monitor some processes CPU with pidstat.

If the PID of my process is for example "1000" i use the command

```
pidstat -p 1000
```

Now imagine that i make a child for that process, that puts the CPU to 80% usage... My problem now is that i can't get that child CPU usage, and i want all the children to be monitored as well since they bellong to my PID 1000... Is there a command on pidstat that gives me the global statistic of a PID and all it's childs in one line?

I can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
pidstat -p 1000 -T CHILD
```

Or for more information about the -T option, execute:

```
man pidstat
```